# Subsetting a range of values from a column variable based on the values of another value

Tags: r, range, subset

I am trying to keep all my rows in the dataframe but DROP the form 2 rows that do not fall with a minimum of 2 years of form 8.

```
library(tidyverse)   

forms <- data_frame( CASEID = rep(01012,5), VISIT = c(450, 450, 365, 365, 450), FORM = c(18, 8, 7, 2, 2), DTYvisit = c(2006, 2006, 2003, 2003, 2006) )

> forms # A tibble: 5 x 4

CASEID VISIT FORM YEAR   

<dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   

1 1012 450 18 2006

2 1012 450 8 2006

3 1012 365 7 2003

4 1012 365 2 2003

5 1012 450 2 2004

6 1013 450 8 2003

7 1013 450 18 2003

8 1013 450 2 2003

9 1012 450 2 2009
```

Any suggestions on how I could drop rows of FORM 2 that do not fall within a < 2 year range of the FORM 8 DTyvisit?

This worked great:

```
form2.matchedOnForm8 <- forms %>% group_by(CASEID) %>% filter(FORM == 8) %>% select(CASEID, VISIT, DTYvisit) %>% left_join(filter(forms, FORM == 2), by = c("CASEID", "VISIT", "DTYvisit")) %>% bind_rows(filter(forms, FORM != 2))
```

but now I am losing observations.

I need the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

forms <- data_frame( CASEID = rep(01012,5), VISIT = c(450, 450, 365, 365, 450), FORM = c(18, 8, 7, 2, 2), DTYvisit = c(2006, 2006, 2003, 2003, 2006) )

> forms # A tibble: 5 x 4

CASEID VISIT FORM YEAR   

<dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>

1 1012 450 18 2006

2 1012 450 8 2006

3 1012 365 7 2003

4 1012 450 2 2004

5 1013 450 8 2003

6 1013 450 18 2003

7 1013 450 2 2003
```

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't understand your question.

Comment: I am losing some observations because some IDs didn't have a form 2 that equaled the date of form 8. So now I need to make sure I am keeping form 2 that equal form 8 years AND keeping form 2 that falls within a min of 2 years that form 8 was taken. It is super convoluted and my intermediate experience doesn't seem to be cutting the cake.

Comment: Why this case **4 1012 365 2 2003** does not include in the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `outer` to calculate the difference between the given YEAR and all YEAR values that FROM 8 might have.

```
min(abs(as.numeric(outer(df[df$FORM==8,'YEAR'],df[1,'YEAR'],'-'))))
[1] 0

df$diff <- apply(df, 1, function(x) min(as.numeric(outer(df[df$FORM==8,'YEAR',drop=TRUE],as.numeric(x['YEAR']),'-'))))

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(CASEID) %>% 
       filter(!(FORM==2 & abs(diff)>2))


df <- read.table(text="
    CASEID VISIT FORM YEAR   

                           1 1012 450 18 2006

                           2 1012 450 8 2006

                           3 1012 365 7 2003

                           4 1012 365 2 2003

                           5 1012 450 2 2004

                           6 1013 450 8 2003

                           7 1013 450 18 2003

                           8 1013 450 2 2003

                           9 1012 450 2 2009
                             ",header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: i'm getting an error:           > min(abs(as.numeric(outer(NPforms.sec2.qol.labs[NPforms.sec2.qol.labs$FORM == 8, 'DTYvisit'], NPforms.sec2.qol.labs[1,'DTYvisit'], '-'))))
Error in FUN(X, Y, ...) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: They were integers but i changed them to numeric and I'm still getting: Error in FUN(X,Y,...) : non-numeric argument in binary operator

Comment: structure(list(CASEID = "01012", VISIT = "450", FORM = 18, DTYvisit = 2006, 
    SDPRS = "09", SDRS = "076", TMAMN = "019", TMANE = "00", 
    TMANP = "25", TMAPR = "00", TMBMN = "051", TMBNE = "00", 
    TMBNP = "25", TMBPR = "00", cohort = "03", BORNY = NA_integer_, 
    EDUCY = NA_character_, HANDD = NA_integer_, HXLEA = NA_integer_, 
    HXLOC = NA_integer_, NLANG = NA_integer_, RACE = NA_integer_

Comment: does it need to be a data.table maybe?  yes, i do have a form 8 :)

Comment: > NPforms.sec2.qol.labs[NPforms.sec2.qol.labs$FORM == 8, "DTYvisit"]
# A tibble: 1,388 x 1
   DTYvisit
      <dbl>
 1     2006
 2     2005
 3     2005
 4     2005
 5     2005
 6     2008
 7     2005
 8     2005
 9     2005
10     2006
# ... with 1,378 more rows
> NPforms.sec2.qol.labs[1, "DTYvisit"]
# A tibble: 1 x 1
  DTYvisit
     <dbl>
1     2006    -> still not working though. maybe I am missing double brackets somewhere? or maybe there is a dplyr way to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176881/discussion-between-a-d-and-a-suliman).

Comment: Is this the same dataset `forms` created by the OP in the post

Comment: @A.Suliman  It is not clear based on the expected output.  With the description, I thought `df %>% group_by(CASEID) %>% filter(abs(YEAR- YEAR[FORM == 8]) <= 3)`

Comment: @akrun Yes it is the same data set. `FORM == 8` may have many years. So the OP would like to exclude any `FORM==2` and YEAR is greater than 2 from any YEAR in `FORM==8`.

Comment: based on your comment `df %>% group_by(CASEID) %>% filter((abs(YEAR- YEAR[FORM == 8]) <= 2)| FORM != 2)`  It is matching the expected output as well

Comment: This what I was try to saying `Warning message:
In YEAR - YEAR[FORM == 8] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`. FORM==8 may have more than one year. So we need to check each YEAR with the all possible YEAR from `FORM==8`

Comment: Here how OP df looks like `df<- structure(list(CASEID = c(1012L, 1012L, 1012L, 1012L, 1012L, 
1013L, 1013L, 1013L, 1012L), VISIT = c(450L, 450L, 365L, 365L, 
450L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 450L), FORM = c(2L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 
8L, 2L, 2L), YEAR = c(2010L, 2006L, 2003L, 2003L, 2004L, 2003L, 
2001L, 2008L, 2004L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"))`

Comment: , `expected_out <- structure(list(CASEID = c(1012L, 1012L, 1012L, 1012L, 1013L, 
1013L, 1012L), VISIT = c(450L, 365L, 365L, 450L, 450L, 450L, 
450L), FORM = c(8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 8L, 2L), YEAR = c(2006L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2004L, 2003L, 2001L, 2004L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "9"))`. Sorry for the inconvience

Comment: @akrun I provide two datasets so you can see the difference. Thanks.

Comment: If there are multiple 8 per each ID, it won't work.  I was only looking at the example in the OP's dataset

Comment: @akrun yes there is multiple year. For that reason I proposed `outer` then`min`